# Getting ERROR 030098 from Generate Service Areas tool of ArcGIS Network Analyst?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, network-analyst, service-area

I'm attempting to run the 'generate service areas' tool. I've just created a network following the instructions [here](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/guide-books/extensions/network-analyst/exercise-1-creating-a-network-dataset.htm) using the data from the Utah Automatic Geographic Reference Center [here](ftp://ftp.agrc.utah.gov/UtahSGID_Vector/UTM12_NAD83/NetworkAnalysis/). I wish to create service areas for a series of points within Utah. There are many points of which i present the lat-lon for 3:

- 40.5361, -112.025
- 40.6874, -111.915
- 40.7095, -112.022

**Procedure**
Download it from AGRC, deleted the 'test', deleted the 'network', and 'network_junctions', leaving on the 'roads' file within the 'network' feature dataset. To reduce the time required to build the network, I selected the road network by location, buffering my  apartment locations by 2 miles, and exported that as a new file in the existing feature dataset as 'roads_2miles'. I then followed the procedures for creating a network according to the tutorial here, for ArcGIS 10.3. I omitted steps 39, 40, and 41 as irrelevant to this task. Building the network took about 2 minutes.

I then attempt to use the 'generate service areas' tool, using my apartment location as the 'facilities' and my 'Network_2miles' network dataset as the Network Dataset. I receive the following error:

> ERROR 030098 The network dataset must have at least one time-based and
>   one distance-based cost attribute.

**What am I doing wrong here?**

Potentially Relevant:
http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/network-analyst-toolbox/make-service-area-layer.htm
http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/network-analyst-toolbox/make-service-area-layer.htm

Answer (score 1):

Looks like my problem was in the original dataset. ArcGIS did not want to recognize F_T_Imp_Min as an impedence field. I copied the dataset out of the feature dataset so I could edit it. I then added two fields which conformed to [ESRI's naming patterns](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/guide-books/extensions/network-analyst/exercise-1-creating-a-network-dataset.htm), FT_Minutes and TF_Minutes, and then rebuilt the network.

Attempts to edit the existing attributes, using [ESRI instructions](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/guide-books/extensions/network-analyst/editing-network-datasets-modifying-network-attributes.htm), I could not seem to get to work.